# How to handle column width resizing event

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qt-signals

I need to handle columns widths resizing in `QTableWidget`.

How can I do this?

--

I talk about event when cursor is under border between to header sections, left mouse button is down and mouse is moving.

Comment: More detail would be helpful, but search for qt event filters

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus It can be done without event filters. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to connect `ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()` (it returns `QHeaderView`) `sectionResized()` signal to some slot.

Working examples:

New signal and slots syntax + lambda expressions

```
connect(ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader(),&QHeaderView::sectionResized,[=]( int logicalIndex, int oldSize, int newSize) {//with lambda
    qDebug() << "works" << logicalIndex << oldSize << newSize;
});
```

Output:

```
works 0 115 116 
works 0 116 115 
works 1 100 101 
works 1 101 102
```

Also add `CONFIG += c++11` to the pro file.

Example with old syntax:

In header:

```
private slots:
   void clicked(int, int, int);
```

In constructor:

```
connect(ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader(),SIGNAL(sectionResized(int,int,int)),this, SLOT(clicked(int,int,int)));
```

Slot:

```
void MainWindow::clicked(int logicalIndex, int oldSize, int newSize)
{
    qDebug() << "works" << logicalIndex << oldSize << newSize;
}
```

Output:

```
works 0 106 107 
works 0 107 108 
works 1 100 101 
works 1 101 102 
works 1 102 103
```

Choose the best for you, but note that new syntax has:

- Compile time check of the existence of the signals and slot, of the
  types, or if the Q_OBJECT is missing.
- Argument can be by typedefs or with different namespace specifier,
  and it works.
- Possibility to automatically cast the types if there is implicit
  conversion (e.g. from QString to QVariant)
- It is possible to connect to any member function of QObject, not only
  slots.

See more information: http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: @Ufx I added more useful information, you should use another signal, but I tested it and it works now. I added very detail explanation.